# How do I set the protocol when using RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https

The action I target needs https. I already have a filter in place that redirects to https if a request comes in via http, but I would prefer to send the request via https right from the start.

**EDIT**

There was an answer from Darin (updated now to something else ) where he asked why I call this first action by http anyway. He had a good point there and I just updated a couple of links. This was the easiest and securest way to fix my problem.

Once I find the time to evaluate çağdaş answer I will use this as the correct answer, because I guess thats of interest for some other people (...including me in the future)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if you must use `RedirectToAction` but with a `UrlHelper` and the controller's `Redirect` method you can do this :

```
public ActionResult SomeAction() {
    UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
    return Redirect(u.Action("actionName", "controllerName", null, "https"));
}
```

Comment: To be honest I dont know the difference between Redirect and RedirectToAction. Maybe there is a difference when TempData is used. I have to to try this one. Looks perfect so far.

Comment: @Malcolm Frexner Well, the difference is that one of them (`Redirect`) takes URI as parameter, whereas the other one takes "some values dictionary" (quoting the source code). And also, there shouldn't be any problems with the TempData, since they both redirect the same way in the end.

Comment: This is a really odd thing to have to do, but it does work.  Surely lots of people have to flip over to a secure cart and then flip back to vanilla http when the checkout is complete.  I'm surprised there isn't an option with the regular RedirectToAction functions.

Comment: Another option you can go with instead of creating a new UrlHelper object is by using `Url.Action`, which is a UrlHelper object already created with the controller, assuming that the class inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 3 includes the [RequireHttpsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which may be of assistance.