# Redirect loop with SSL action filter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, action-filter

I am using an ActionFilter (see below) to detect whether or not 1. the current controller/action requires SSL and 2. SSL is currently being used, and redirect accordingly.

This works fine locally (using a dummy cert in IIS 7) but once I get it up on the server I get an error indicating an infinite redirect loop.

Any ideas?

```
 public class SslFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public SslFilter(bool sslRequired)
    {
        SslRequired = sslRequired;
    }

    public bool SslRequired { get; set; }


    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url);

        if (SslRequired && !req.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
            builder.Port = 443;
            res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());

        }
        else if (!SslRequired && req.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
            builder.Port = 80;
            res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Firefox error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server
>   is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused
>   by disabling or refusing to accept
>   cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Try redirecting in a more MVCish way:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url);

if (SslRequired && !req.IsSecureConnection)
{
    builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
    builder.Port = 443;
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(builder.Uri.ToString());
    filterContext.Cancel = true;
}
else if (!SslRequired && req.IsSecureConnection)
{
    builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
    builder.Port = 80;
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(builder.Uri.ToString());
    filterContext.Cancel = true;
}
else 
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: We tried this approach and Alex H's original approach - in both cases they worked in our dev environments but not in production. However, the accepted approach in this question did work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302081/how-do-i-set-the-protocoll-when-using-redirecttoaction

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on a site that I'm building and found that for some reason it had to do with having the port number in the url. So, builder.Uri.ToString() was outputting http://domain.com:80/ or https://domain.com:443/, which as far as I am aware should be fine, but we switched to use builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri and it fixed the issue. Here is a sample of our code...

```
UriBuilder __urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(__context.Request.Url);
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme.Contains("https")) {
  if (this.Required == RequiredStates.Required) {
    __urlBuilder.Scheme = "https";
    __urlBuilder.Port = 443;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(__urlBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, true);
  }
}
else {
  if (this.Required == RequiredStates.NotRequired) {
    __urlBuilder.Scheme = "http";
    __urlBuilder.Port = 80;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(__urlBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check certificate installed on the server. Use the SSL configuration tool from MS to detect the issue. Most probably the private is missing.