# Enable and require SSL for certain actions in an MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, security

I am busy setting up a protocol between my payments service provider and my site.  They use Immediate Payment Notification (IPN), where they contact a URL in my site when the payment is processed, sending me confirmation data.  I would like to secure this URL, and one or two others, using SSL.  The majority of actions don't require this, as no sensitive data is passed during normal operations, only payments, logins, and uploads.

Comment: You can add a custom Require SSL Attribute as described [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323544/redirect-loop-with-ssl-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Ofer Zelig, I think my question is easily enough inferred from my stating what I wish to do.  If I knew how to do it, I would not abuse a question and answer forum to burden other users with a mere statement of my intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be able to just add the [RequireHttps] annotation to the action:

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult processOverSSL ()
{

}
```

As long as IIS is configured for SSL with a certificate, it should just redirect to https.

Comment: The problem with this is that sensitive data can be sent with the first request as clear text. It will redirect after that but the data will have been sent unencrypted already.